# variable name in Javascript (in specific case)

Tags: jquery

Select the country will decide cities list in second dropdown list.

https://jsfiddle.net/k18etgex/11/

It works with countries name which is one word such as "Úc", "Pháp", "Mỹ".

```
var Úc = [
    {display: "Canberra", value: "Canberra" }, 
    {display: "Sydney", value: "Sydney" }, 
    {display: "Melbourne", value: "Melbourne" },
    {display: "Perth", value: "Perth" },
    {display: "Gold Coast ", value: "Gold-Coast" }];

var Pháp = [
    {display: "Paris", value: "Paris" }, 
    {display: "Avignon", value: "Avignon" }, 
    {display: "Strasbourg", value: "Strasbourg" },
    {display: "Nice", value: "Nice" }];
```

But it does not work with country which name is two word such as "Nhật Bản"

```
var Nhật Bản = [
    {display: "Tokyo", value: "Tokyo" }, 
    {display: "Osaka", value: "Osaka" } 
    ];
```

AND I am not allowed to change anything of first dropdown box.

```
Country:
            <select name="departure_country[]" data-required="1" data-type="select">
                                    <option value="">- Chọn nước -</option>
                                                        <option value="Mỹ">Mỹ</option>                      <option value="Úc">Úc</option>                      <option value="Pháp">Pháp</option>
                            <option value="Nhật Bản">Nhật Bản</option>
                            </select>
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: put underscore in between. `var Nhật_Bản` Read: A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).

Comment: Variable names shouldn't have got special chars, spaces or reserved words. Don't make that. Variable names can be what you want, doesn't need to retrieve from html, that's a bad practice and it return most common problems and fails.

Comment: `<option value="Nhật Bản">` is a value, not a variable name. Don't use that value to a variable name ....

Comment: I don't know how to said to you that more clear.

Comment: then I have to change <option value="Nhật Bản"> to <option value="Nhật_Bản">. it does not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the various arrays into a single object, accessed via `[]` notation.

```js
var cities = {

  "Úc": [{
    display: "Canberra",
    value: "Canberra"
  }, {
    display: "Sydney",
    value: "Sydney"
  }, {
    display: "Melbourne",
    value: "Melbourne"
  }, {
    display: "Perth",
    value: "Perth"
  }, {
    display: "Gold Coast ",
    value: "Gold-Coast"
  }],

  "Pháp": [{
    display: "Paris",
    value: "Paris"
  }, {
    display: "Avignon",
    value: "Avignon"
  }, {
    display: "Strasbourg",
    value: "Strasbourg"
  }, {
    display: "Nice",
    value: "Nice"
  }],

  "Nhật Bản": [{
    display: "Tokyo",
    value: "Tokyo"
  }, {
    display: "Osaka",
    value: "Osaka"
  }]
};

(function($) {
  $('[name="departure_country[]"]').change(
    function() {
      var country = $(this).val();
      
      var clist = cities[country];
      
      var dep = $('[name="departure[]"]');
                  
      dep.empty().append('<option>--select--</option>');
      
      $(clist).each(
        function(i, v) {
          $('<option>').text(v.display).val(v.value).appendTo(dep);
        }
      );
      }
  );
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="departure_country[]" data-required="1" data-type="select">
  <option value="">- Chọn nước -</option>
  <option value="Mỹ">Mỹ</option>
  <option value="Úc">Úc</option>
  <option value="Pháp">Pháp</option>
  <option value="Nhật Bản">Nhật Bản</option>
</select>

<select name="departure[]" data-required="1" data-type="select">
  <option value="">- Chọn TP -</option>
  <option value="Hồ Chí Minh">Hồ Chí Minh</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an object as

```
var countries = {
    "Nhật Bản" : [
        {display: "Tokyo", value: "Tokyo" }, 
        {display: "Osaka", value: "Osaka" } 
        ];
}
```

Then can access it using bracket notation

```
countries["Nhật Bản"]
```